# How do I untar a set of files in a directory?

Tags: files, tar

There are about 10,000 files in the directory some of which are .fits and some of which are .tar. Now, I need to untar only the .tar files. Although running an if condition seems reasonable, the untar command "xvf" only works on a per-file basis, which defeats the use of a loop.

Comment: Welcome to Unix Stackexchange! You can [take the tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) first and the learn [How to Ask a good question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the untar command "xvf" only works on a per-file basis

which makes the use of loop *necessary*:

```
for file in ./*.tar; do tar xvf "$file"; done
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually with `find` you can do the job without loops. Like this:

```
find -iname '*.tar' -maxdepth 1 -exec tar xvf '{}' \;
```

The logic is like this:

- `-iname` matches files with extension `.tar` (case insensitive), and
- `-maxdepth 1` limits the matching range to depth 1 (so that `./*/*.tar` and the like won't get matched)
- finally `-exec` performs the `tar xvf` command on the matched files (note that `;` and `{}` need escaping; refer to `find(1)` for more information)